# Containing a text within a fixed-width div with "white-space: pre;"

Tags: css, node.js, express, view, pug

If the title is a little bit vague, allow me to explain.

I'm making a small Q&A app using NodeJS, MongoDB and Express.

Currently I'm doing the layouting part using CSS.

I have a small textarea, in which you can submit text, after you click the submit button, you are redirected to a page displaying the data you just inputted through the forms.

However, the main body of the text overflows the max-width I set for the div, this happened after I added the "white-space: pre;" property to enable line breaks in the post. Before that, the text would stay within the 960px width I defined for the div, but there wouldn't be any line breaks.

Jade code for this view:

```
extends layout

block content
    div.pageContainer
        h1 #{discussion.title}
        span(id="categoryMarker" style="font-size: 1.25em;") &#34;#{discussion.category}&#34;

        h3 #{discussion.author}
            | &nbsp;-&nbsp;&nbsp;
            span Created on #{discussion.date.toDateString()}
            br
            br
            div#bodyText
                p #{discussion.body}

    footer
        div.wrapper
          a.hvr-grow(href="/discussions") Back to all threads
          span.hvr-grow(style="color:white;") &nbsp;&nbsp;-&nbsp;&nbsp;
          a.hvr-grow(href="/discussions/create") Start a thread
```

CSS stylesheet (Relevant to the p where the input from the textarea displays)

```
#bodyText
{
    font-size: 0.75em;
    font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    max-width: 960px;
}

#bodyText p
{
    white-space: pre;
}
```

My text overflows like so: http://puu.sh/hC9ba/c7d7984e58.jpg

It should not do this. I look forward to any suggestion or tip.

Comment: did you tried pre-line instead of pre?

Comment: Pre-line works as well as "pre-wrap", this is solved! Thank you all for your swift comments

Comment: if you solved your problem then post as a answer to help others

Answer (score 2):

Try  `white-space: pre-line` instead of `word-wrap: pre`

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this answer for me was using:

```
#bodyText p
{
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

Thanks to everyone who answered and tried to help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried word-wrap?

```
#bodyText p
{
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: This does break but does not preserve the whitespaces (the line breaks).